# Testing for when malloc returns NULL

Tags: c, macos, unit-testing

I'm trying to replicate the `strdup` function in C. It's part of an exercise for school. I'd like to unit test it, including the case where `malloc` returns `NULL` and sets `errno` to `ENOMEM`.

I'm on OSX 10.8.

I've tried limiting the stacksize, then datasize, realizing malloc allocates on the heap:

```
limit stacksize 0
limit datasize 0
```

Confirmation that limiting should have worked:

```
my-host% limit
cputime         unlimited
filesize        unlimited
datasize        0kB
stacksize       0kB
coredumpsize    0kB
addressspace    unlimited
memorylocked    unlimited
maxproc         709
descriptors     256
```

However, even with a limit of 0kB for the stack size, I am able to run programs just fine. So I'm thinking there might be a restriction on my host on the minimum stack size.

How else could I test the case where `malloc` returns `NULL`?

Comment: Replace it with a mock?

Comment: The issue isn't with stack size, it's the heap. Maybe addressspace sets a heap limit, not sure.

Comment: Allocate big chunks until malloc fails, then call your strdup.

Comment: The stack size does not affect how much memory you allocate on the heap.

Comment: @KerrekSB - What do you mean by mock?

Comment: To clear up the ***[stack/heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)*** confusion (for those of ***us*** needing it)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I realized that, which is why I had tried limiting the datasize.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but the best approach IMO is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168388/how-to-replace-default-malloc-by-code

Comment: @KerrekSB: I've tried that, using #define and #undef. I've also thought about redefining malloc, but that would make every function that needs regular malloc bug, no?

Comment: @conradk: Well, the point of a **unit** test is that you don't have any other functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you fake the memory allocation failure.  For example, I needed to test memory failure during allocation of a 3D array (lots of memory to clean up), so I used a framework where the function `xmalloc()` was called to get memory, and the test program controlled when `xmalloc()` would fail.

```
static int fail_after = 0;
static int num_allocs = 0;

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    if (fail_after > 0 && num_allocs++ >= fail_after)
    {
        fputs("Out of memory\n", stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    return malloc(size);
}

...code using xmalloc...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int no1 = 5;
    int fail_limit = 33;

    if (argc == 2)
        fail_limit = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (fail_after = 0; fail_after < fail_limit; fail_after++)
    {
        printf("Fail after: %d\n", fail_after);
        num_allocs = 0;
        test_allocation(no1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Write your `strdup()` surrogate to use `xmalloc()` instead of `malloc()`.  Test it more or less as shown.  You can get fancier with the 'out of memory' requirements; this is rudimentary but effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this with the mock object support of the [cmocka](http://cmocka.org/) unit testing framework.