# Replacing malloc via shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, malloc, shared-libraries

I'm working on a cmake based project in Unix environment. I've created a shared library `myMalloc.so` where I've defined my own malloc/free/realloc etc.:

```
//   myMalloc.cpp

extern "C" __typeof (malloc) __libc_malloc;
extern "C" {

void* malloc( size_t _size )
{
    /*some code that allows me to determine if this version of malloc was called*/
    return __libc_malloc( _size );
}
}
```

Some other shared library `proxy.so` is linked with `myMalloc.so`. Finally `proxy.so` is linked with the executable binary.

The issue is that default glibc malloc is used in the executable instead of my own malloc.

I've tried adding below flags into multiple different CMakeLists.txt files

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-calloc -fno-builtin-realloc -fno-builtin-free")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-calloc -fno-builtin-realloc -fno-builtin-free")
```

but it didn't help.

I've checked `readelf -Ws myMalloc.so` and can see my version of malloc marked as GLOBAL, shown before any other malloc

```
58: 0000000000017110    79 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 malloc
255: 0000000000017110    79 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 malloc
304: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_malloc
```

Then I've checked `readelf -Ws proxy.so` and sadly, glibc malloc is visible earlier than my custom malloc (I'm guessing that it means glibc version will be preferred)

```
72: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5 (10)
450: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND malloc
```

`readelf -Ws` on the executable doesn't list any version of malloc

Compiling `myMalloc` as static lib doesn't help, but **compiling both `myMalloc` and `proxy` as static libs seems to help** (malloc is also then visible on symbol table of the executable).

Sadly, this is not an option and these libs need to remain shared and I cannot use LD_PRELOAD trick

What could be wrong ? I'm guessing that some other library which uses glibc malloc is linked earlier, but I have no idea how to approach this. I hoped that flags in cmake mentioned earlier would help, but apparently they don't.

I've spent a few days digging through the internet over this as my makefiles/linker knowledge is somewhat limited and couldn't find much more info, I'll appreciate any suggestions.

*Edit: I don't see how the marked duplicate question answers my question.. I have a specific issue related with shared libraries while linking isn't even mentioned in the duplicate.*

Comment: Yes, none of the duplicates actually addresses the problem in the question. Reopened.

Comment: If you are on linux, you may be interested in the `--wrap` option of `ld`. The manual describes an example precisely about `malloc`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168388/how-to-replace-default-malloc-by-code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172988/in-c-is-it-possible-to-change-exported-function-name-to-different-one/12173140#12173140, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023018/overriding-c-library-functions-calling-original.  Do none of these methods work for you?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html just LD_PRELOAD it.

Comment: How is proxy.so linked/loaded to the executable?